# Getting Connection Refused while doing port forwarding

Tags: android, web-services, connection, connection-refused

I have a web service running in my local machine. I created an app that runs on my Android device. Both of them are in the same Wi-Fi. I am able to access the web service from my Android mobile using Chrome. However, when I try to access it from my app, I get Connection Refused error regularly. But some times, it works fine.
I am using this for enabling port forwarding:
chrome://inspect/#devices

What could be the reason for this intermittent error?

Comment: I suggest you post your web service logs from that time, as much information as possible about your requests / responses, any correlation you've noticed between successful and unsuccessful requests, etc.

Comment: It is resolved now. I made my wifi connection as a Private one able to call the web service without any portforwarding.